# Sample space for die throwing experiment

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I am throwing $8$ non-identical dice, and I want to find the probability of getting a sum of the numbers on the dice equal to $30$.

The number of ways of getting the sum equal to $30$ is $125588$ (using multinomial theorem).

Is this the number of favorable cases?

What will be the sample space?

I am a little confused, please help me out...

Comment: The sample space I suppose is going to be all the different 8-tuples with the number on each die. Since each die has 6 different possibilities, we have $6^8$ possible outcomes. Do you agree?

Comment: Are the dice fair and six-sided?

Comment: @satishramanathan Yes..Calculation error, but still i am getting 125588

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi I do not know.. how can we conclude that?

Comment: "i want to find the probability of getting the sum of the numbers on the dies = 30" OK. "What will be the sample space?" How is the latter useful to the former?

Comment: @Did For finding the probability, i will divide the number of favorable cases by the total in the sample space..

Comment: @satishramanathan I still think that the sample space will be the one suggested by Zaidi

Comment: @Pkwssis, thinking a little deeper, both of them are the same.  the sum of the frequency distribution of the sum and the total different 8 tuples are indeed the same.

Comment: Several sample spaces fit the bill here. What counts really is the couple (sample space,probability measure).

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

Number of favorable cases $ = (-1)^0 {8\choose0}{29\choose7}+(-1)^1 {8\choose1}{23\choose7}+(-1)^2 {8\choose2}{17\choose7}+(-1)^3 {8\choose3}{11\choose7} = 1560780 - 8*245157 + 28*19448-56*330 =125588$

In general, the formula for finding the distribution of sum s in throwing n dice with x sides goes like this

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{[(s-n)/x]} -1^k {n\choose k}{(s-1-xk)\choose (x-1)}$$

Comment: I [wolfram'ed it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+of+x%5E30+in+%28x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%29%5E8)

Comment: If you cannot give some explanation going along then this answer is not much more than a number.